# How to get sms text from incoming sms in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, sms

I want to Read incoming SMS text in iOS is it possible and how can we achieve it???,
It's already done in [babel](https://itunes.apple.com/app/babel-encrypted-messaging/id637468137?ign-mpt=uo=5) application at appstore. i am try to googling but, unable to find any piece of code how to do that? if you already known about that can you please share your knowledge.

Comment: Possible at ios 12.
But not the integrity SMS ..
[Click here to see more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50791050/ios-12-sms-reading-api/52550921#52550921)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No way `Not Possible`. `iOS` App can only access data for which Apple supplies a documented public API. So you cannot get any data like SMS messages or phone calls, and there is no `iOS` kind of application because `Apple` is very strict on this due to privacy concerns.

`Intercepting/reading incoming SMS is not possible on iOS (for privacy reasons)`

If an app does that, I don't know if Apple will approve. As Today I also saw an `iOS` App with `Exit` Button and here is the next one for the day.

**INSTALL APP** :

As per your detail for `Bebal` iOS app I just downloaded it and reviewed it. Here are the steps:

Enter Phone Number, No Verification message found. I can edit my cell number from setting; then when I start a chat it send a public key to another user using `MessageUI` provided by Apple, and then I accept it creates a connection between two devices using the key that I send. So after that, I can communicate with other through the `Bebal` app server.

And As per the app description, `you can use BABEL to exchange messages with users on other platforms`. Messages the app receiving using the Internal Server, so final summary is there is no way to read an incoming message in iOS app

Please review and let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: I think they get the data from server and fill automatically in it.There is no possible way of getting the sms data without jailbreak.

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer is It is **NOT possible** in iOS device *(non jailbroken)* you cannot get any data on SMS messages or phone calls, so the best way is stop fighting with it. Not sure but it may achieve by jailbroken device.

> **Apple said -** In iPhone OS 4.0 and later, you can send text messages from within your application. This feature is strictly for sending messages. Incoming SMS messages go to the built-in Messages app.

Comment: but, i am using unlocked device it is not jailbroken device(iPhone 4 with Running iOS 7.1.1).

Comment: is there any way to read incoming sms from notification center?

Comment: Ummmm, It's may be not possible dude :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to jailbreak and install from cydia like this app https://ikeymonitor.com/download