# Does Apple allow us to intercept incoming gsm messages?

Tags: ios, iphone

Whether it is legal or not?
I am implementing OTP verification for my app

Comment: NO. Apple doesn't allow you for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Apple is concerned about privacy as you may know.

A response is quoted below from apple discussion [forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1936935?tstart=0),also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968471/how-to-get-sms-text-from-incoming-sms-in-ios)

[image]