# iOS 12 SMS Reading API?

Tags: ios, sms, ios12

In Beta version of iOS 12 I have observed it gives OTP(from SMS) in keyboard suggestion.
So is there any API which they have created for developers ? Or that would just be an OS feature.

Answer (score 9):

It is OS feature but you need to set `UITextField`'s input view’s `textContentType` property `oneTimeCode`.

```
otpTextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

**NOTE:** Security Code AutoFill will only works with System Keyboard it will not work with custom keyboard.

When you get OTP it will look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, you can't read the full message, you can only read the verify-code in the message.

**Swift:**

```
@available(iOS 12.0, *)
public static let oneTimeCode: UITextContentType

myTextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

**Objective-C:**

```
UITextContentType const UITextContentTypeOneTimeCode NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(12_0);

myTextField.textContentType = UITextContentTypeOneTimeCode;
```

---

*These following verification code CAN be recognized by the system:*

***A pure number of lengths of 3-8***

like : 123 1234 12345 666666 1234567 12345678 ...

---

*These following verification code CANNOT be recognized by the system:*

***(i).length of code is less than 3 or more than 8
(ii).include letters***

like : 1 12 123a 9h7d 123456789 ...

---

Others:

***Security Code AutoFill will only works with System Keyboard. It will not work with custom keyboard.***

Comment: What is the source of your info? Can we get a link.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky Do you mean the test info ? No source. This is the result from my own test..

Comment: The yellow text, the symbol ">", is used to quote something. I asked because it seemed you quoted some reference.

Comment: I also saw that the limit of characters of the SMS is 70!

Comment: @mattyU Where did you see it?

Comment: @刘俊利 it's the result of my test!

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=z0i801mg and https://wicg.github.io/sms-one-time-codes/#format

Answer (score 4):

There is no api, but you need set `textContentType` as `.oneTimeCode` of `UITextField` property

```
otpTextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

one more thing,

> If you use a custom input view for text field,
>   iOS cannot display the necessary AutoFill UI.

[Click here for more info by apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to other answers, after testing it seems that the text message needs to include either "Verification number" or "Code" before the number to work properly.

Working:

- Verification number 1234
- Verification number: 1234
- Verification code 1234
- Verification code: 1234
- Code 1234
- Code: 1234
- OTP 1234
- OTP: 1234

Not working:

- Number 1234
- Verification 1234
- 1234

Answer (score 1):

Worthg mentioning that it seems "Autofill Passowrds" keyboard option needs to be turned on on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no public API for that. It is automatically handled by OS.
You just need to set UITextField's input view’s textContentType property to oneTimeCode.

textField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode