# How to implement AutoFill OTP verification and Auto Proceed in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, one-time-password

I am trying to use Auto Fill OTP but it is not working. Anyone help me.

```
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
     otpField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
}
```

Comment: This Reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704028/ios-12-otp-keyboard-suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've to implement `AutoFill-OTP` in **iOS** then it requires iOS 12 and above

You've to set `TextField` `ContentType` to `OneTimeCode` as below image

- Image

[image]

> Note:- It only works when **OTP** message is included `Code` or `PassCode` keyword.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. When Message included "OTP" key word.

Comment: @NguyễnKhắcHoàng welcome

Comment: will otp suggestion above keyboard work with IQKeyboardManager?